# Submit form with Ajax not working.

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So i have been on the web reading for the entire evening on how to fix this but nothing seems to work that i try. So I am going to reach out here to try and see if there is help to be recieved. I am trying to submit a form on my website with ajax so that I dont have to reload the page. However the form submits and redirects normal anyway. The code i have going looks like this. The prevent works at some times and at others not. If there is any more information i can provide please do let me know. Best regards.

```
function validateForm() {

var allFilled = true;
$('input[type=text].required').each(function() { //See so nothing is empty
    if($(this).val() == ""){allFilled = false;}
});

if(allFilled === false){return [false, "Alla fälten måste vara ifyllda"]}

var dateInput = $("#datepicker").val();
if(!moment(dateInput, 'DD/MM-YYYY',true).isValid()){ //Validate the date if its in the right format
    return [false, "Datumet måste vara formaterat DD/MM-YYYY"];
}

var lastDateInput = $("#datepicker2").val();
if(!moment(lastDateInput, 'DD/MM-YYYY',true).isValid()){ //Validate the date if its in the right format
    return [false, "Senaste datumet för anmälan måste vara formaterat DD/MM-YYYY"];
}

if(!/^\d{2}:\d{2}$/.test($("#clockpicker").val())){ // Check the time format HH:MM
  return [false, "Den angivna tiden måste vara formaterad HH:MM"];
}

var acceptedHalfTimeLength = $("#halftimeLength").val();
var acceptedHalfTimeLengths = [10,15,20,30,40,45];
var validLength = false;
for(var i = 0; i < acceptedHalfTimeLengths.length;i++){ //The value has to be some of the following in the array
  if(parseInt($acceptedHalfTimeLength) === acceptedHalfTimeLengths[i]){
    validLength = true; 
  }
}
if(validLength === false){
  return [false, "Den angivna halvlekstiden stämmer ej in på de accepterade längderna"]
}

return [true, "Match added"];
}
```

I use this to make sure all the inputs from the user is formated correctly.

Then i do action accordingly.

```
$( "#myform" ).on( "submit", function(event) {

event.preventDefault();

var validateResult = validateForm();
var validateBoolean = validateResult[0];
var validateMessage = validateResult[1];


var lat = marker.getPosition().lat(); //From map
var long = marker.getPosition().lng();
if(validateBoolean === true){
  $.ajax(
   {
     type : "POST",
     url : "add.php";
     data : $("#myform").serialize() + "&lat=" + lat + "&long=" + long,
     success:function(result){
       alert("Game added");
     }
  }
  );
}else{
  document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = validateMessage;
  $("#alert").effect( "shake", {times:4}, 1000 );
}
});
```

Where the php script to be ran with the ajax looks as the following.

add.php

```
  <?php

include_once "DBH.php";


$date       = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['date']);
$teamOne    = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['teamOne']);
$teamTwo    = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['teamTwo']);
$arena      = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['arena']);
$halftimeLength = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['halftimeLength']);
$gender     = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['gender']);
$yob        = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['yob']);
$salary     = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['salary']);
$lastDate   = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lastDate']);
$time       = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['startTime']);
$lat        = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lat']);
$long       = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['long']);

//Create a dateobject from the string that comes from the input and format it.
$formatedDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m-Y', $date)->format('Y-m-d');
$formatedLastDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m-Y', $lastDate)->format('Y-m-d');

$sql = "INSERT INTO games (`date`, `teamOne`, `teamTwo`, `arena`, `halftimelength`, `gender`, `kull`, `salary`, `lastDate`, `time`, `lat`, `long`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
  echo "Main statement failed";
}else{
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssssssssdd", $formatedDate, $teamOne, $teamTwo, $arena, $halftimeLength, $gender, $yob, $salary, $formatedLastDate, $time, $lat, $long);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}

?>
```

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. `$acceptedHalfTimeLength` should be `acceptedHalfTimeLength`, `url : "add.php";` should be `url : "add.php",`.

Comment: ^ Fix that semicolon and it should eliminate the js failed to compile errors. And always, learn to use the dev tools in the web browser. It will save you lots of head scratching and hours looking for answers. This site is also a valuable tool when doing extended js blocks: http://jshint.com/

Answer (score 0):

try to Set the values in a array, like that:

```
var obj = {
    "getListaHoteis": true,
    "estado" : $("#selEstado").val(), //value of your input 1
    "cidade" : $("#selCidade").val(), //value of your input 2
    "dispo" : getDisponibilidade(), //value of your input 3
    "aceita_pet" : $('#chkPet').is(':checked'), //value of your input 4
    "dist_praia" : distPraia, //value of your input 4
    "tipo_lugar" : $("#seltipoLugar").val() //value of your input 4
};
```

And after that send to $.ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "getListaHoteis.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: obj,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (dt) { console.log(dt) };});
```